# Using mysql in a html document

Tags: html, mysql, ruby-on-rails

Im using ruby on rails and mysql to hold my database. I'm struggling to understand how I would take information from my database and use it in a html page (that i would then display).

For instance, if in my database there is a table called Users. How would I display all the user names (ie SELECT names FROM Users) in my html page (in the Views folder in my rails app)?

I've just started learning this stuff so sorry if its a really trivial question! I'm just not understanding some of the explanations on the web.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Rails you have models which interacts with database. If you want to connect to users table you should create model.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

def self.names
  User.select('name')
end

end
```

And to create view you should have controller which can have index action:

```
class UserController < ApplicationController

  def index
     @names = User.names
  end
end
```

In Views folder you can have users folder with index.html.erb

In this html file you can access @names and iterate over them and display names.

You also have to define route in route.rb

```
resources :user
```

and access link as /users

You can refer rails tutorial: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm trying to do it now.
in the html file, how do you access that info?
as in, do you just do <% @names %>??

Comment: You have to iterate over it or <%= @names.collect(&:name) %>

Comment: I tried that, but it gives me undefined method collect. Do I have to add a new method collect in UserController?

Comment: Can you tell me result of @names ? collect methods works on array. It should work as it is built in method

Comment: NoMethodError in Pages#login

<!DOCTYPE html>

<h1> TITLE </h1>

<%= @firstnames.collect(&:firstname) %>


</html>


This is the error I'm getting. (btw, sorry for some of these questions, I know they are pretty basic, but I'm really new to this and I'm not getting a lot of the online material)

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-views.htm .. This link will help you